# Correct usage of the phrase 'if any'

Tags: phrases, expressions, word-order, prepositional-phrases

What is the best position for the phrase 'if any' for the sentence below? Please, explain the rationale behind your answers.

> What could be, **if any**, the benefits or disadvantages of something?
>
> What could be the benefits or disadvantages, **if any**, of something?
>
> What could be the benefits or disadvantages of something, **if any**?

Thanks!

Comment: Without any more information, there is no *best* position. It's purely a matter of preference.

Comment: What, if any, could be the benefits or disadvantages of something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The corpus data show clearly that if any is usually used after a noun, sometimes after few. So the second sentence is the best choice. examples: And do you know what services , if any, they performed while they were there? New York decisions shall be cited from the official reports , if any. What impact , if any, the transaction has on the public safety. Having said this, I think it is also fair to say that there are few , if any, good scientific studies to back this up.

Answer (score 2):

1. The **1st sentence** is not lucid enough.  The *if any* applies to *What* which also points to *benefits and disadvantages*.
2. The **2nd sentence** is the best way- it avoids ambiguity and also since the intent is to ask **if there are any** *benefits or disadvantages* of something.  The **1st sentence** and **2nd sentence** mean the same.
3. The **3rd sentence** says: if there is 'something', what are its benefits or disadvantages.  I am pretty sure that is not what the writer intends to ask.

I am a lawyer and the above is based on what I have read in various enactments and elsewhere.